# route model binding with query strings

Tags: php, laravel

If I have a url like this:

```
localhost:8000?campaign=1
```

Is it possible to fetch the campaign from db like what we do in **route model binding**

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `localhost:8000?campaign=1` you should pass query string as: `localhost:8000/campaign/1`

and in Route:

```
Route::get('campaign/{id}', ['as' => 'campaigns.index', 'uses' => 'CampaignController@index']);
```

and in Controller:

```
public function index($id)
{
    //Your Code Goes Here
}
```

That's it! :)

Comment: thanks for reply, but i want it to be a query string

Comment: then still you can get this as: $request->input('campaign');

Comment: i want to have the campaign information with id of 1 and use its fields

Comment: without some logic you can not do it, basically you wants model to read the query string automatically and retrieve the data from database, this is impossible